# Why doesn’t screen capture videos doesn’t show up in Video app or any other video players in iPad?

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, video, screen-capture

I’m using the built in screen capture to capture videos. They only seem to show up in the “Photos” app under “Videos” section. I really don’t like the Video player (with frames and stuff at the bottom). Why doesn’t a screen capture show up in “Videos” app or any other external players like VLC? What can I do to change the default player of screen captures on iPad?

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no way to change the default app that opens a particular file type, hyperlink, etc.

However, many 3rd party apps allow you to import and/or open photos, videos etc directly from their default locations without first having to transfer the files via iTunes or an online cloud service.

With regard to VLC, if you don't want to connect your iPad to iTunes, then your best bet is to go into the Photos app and save the videos to Files, Dropbox, Google Drive, etc. One saved, go into VLC and access the sidebar, tap on Cloud Services, and then select the appropriate option to access the video.

For example, to access a video capture on VLC, you could:

1. Go to Photos
2. Tap the video
3. Tap on the Share icon and select Save to Files
4. Navigate to where within Files you want to save the video and proceed to save it
5. Open VLC
6. Access the sidebar
7. Tap on Cloud Services
8. In the next screen tap on Cloud Services again
9. Open the video capture

Comment: That's much better answer then my rant

Answer (score 0):

That's more about how non-apple apps can access your private data (which by default are only accessible to built-in apps) - Check if there are any privacy/accessibility settings that needs extra user consent - either 'access to' and/or 'access from' - should be in the privacy tab - if you still can't share it directly you probably must use the [share/copy to/open with] button and dump it into vlc directly (which sucks, i know, i do the same each time shuffling ebooks formats from one app to another - apps data are kept seperatly and you cant diretly access them like on your local drive, icloud drive mitigates that partially so check if you can acccess those videos through icloud.